# Crack detection using opencv

Tags: opencv

> Hey I have a code of crack detection but while running the code I got
>   error. Here is the code, the error is in 2.0f and 2.0  when I remove
>   this all related error to this got solved but new error DrawMarker not
>   declared in this scope.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
#define CL_GREEN  Scalar(0  , 255, 0  )
#define CL_RED    Scalar(0  , 0  , 255)
#define CL_BLU    Scalar(255, 0  , 0  )
#define CL_BLACK  Scalar(0  , 0  , 0  )     
void Morph(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, int operation =    cv::MORPH_OPEN, 
int kernel_type = cv::MORPH_RECT, int size = 1);
struct contourStats{
double area, perimeter, axisMin, axisMax, axisAvg, eccentricity, axisRatio, circularity;
Point2d center;
RotatedRect rr;
contourStats(){}
contourStats(const vector<Point> &contour)
{
    calculateStats(contour);
}
void calculateStats(const vector<Point> &contour)
{
    Moments m = cv::moments(contour, true);
    area = m.m00;
    center = Point2f(-1, -1);
    if (area > 0){
        center.x = cvRound(m.m10 / m.m00);
        center.y = cvRound(m.m01 / m.m00);
    }
    eccentricity = DBL_MAX;
    if ((m.m20 + m.m02) > 0)
        eccentricity = (pow((m.m20 - m.m02), 2) - 4 * m.m11 * m.m11) / pow((m.m20 + m.m02), 2);
    // axis ratio:circles have ratio=1 lines have ratio->0
    rr = minAreaRect(contour);
    axisMin = min(rr.size.height, rr.size.width);
    axisMax = max(rr.size.height, rr.size.width);
    axisAvg = (axisMin+axisMax) / 2.0;
    axisRatio = axisMax > 0 ? axisMin / axisMax : 0;
    perimeter = arcLength(contour, false);
    circularity = perimeter > 0 ? 4 * CV_PI * area / pow(perimeter, 2) : 0;
}
void printStats(const string &title)
{
    cout << endl << title << endl
        << "\tArea [px^2]: " << area << endl
        << "\tAxis[px]: " << axisMin << "/" << axisMax << endl
        << "\tAxis Ratio: " << axisRatio << endl
        << "\tCircularity: " << circularity << endl
        << "\tAbs(eccentricity): " << abs(eccentricity) << endl;
}
};

       int main(int argc, char** argv)
      {
    Mat src, gray, edges, cracks,tmp;
Mat biscuitMask;
//src = imread("../img/biscotto_rotated.jpg");
src = imread("../img/biscotto.jpg");
cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
// GET ALL EDGES (CRACKS AND BISCUIT)
Canny(gray, edges, 100, 200, 3);
Morph(edges, edges, MORPH_CLOSE, MORPH_ELLIPSE, 5);
// GET THE BISCUIT ONLY
GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(7, 7), 0);
threshold(gray, biscuitMask, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);
// VALIDATE THE BISCUIT
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
biscuitMask.copyTo(tmp);
findContours(tmp, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
if ((contours.size() > 1) || (contours[0].size() < 6)) {
    cerr << "ERROR: invalid mask for the biscuit!";
    return 1;
}
vector<Point> biscuitContour(contours[0]);
contourStats theBiscuit(biscuitContour);
theBiscuit.printStats("BISCUIT STATS:");
if (theBiscuit.circularity < 0.85) {
    cout << "WARNING: invalid biscuit circularity!";
}
drawMarker(src, theBiscuit.center, CL_BLU, MARKER_CROSS, theBiscuit.axisAvg / 8);
circle(src, theBiscuit.center, theBiscuit.axisAvg / 2, CL_BLU, 2);
//polylines(src, biscuitContour, true, CL_GREEN); 

// GET ONLY THE CRACKS INSIDE THE BISCUIT
Morph(biscuitMask, biscuitMask, MORPH_ERODE,MORPH_ELLIPSE, 5);
cracks = (edges & biscuitMask);
imshow("cracks", cracks);

findContours(cracks, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

double minLenght = theBiscuit.axisAvg / 2;
double maxLenght = 0;
int biggest = -1;
vector<contourStats> crackStats(contours.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    drawContours(src, contours, i, CL_GREEN, 1); //all contours in GREEN
    crackStats[i].calculateStats(contours[i]);   //analize potential cracks
    if (crackStats[i].axisMax < minLenght)       //ignore short contours
        continue;
    drawContours(src, contours, i, CL_RED, 1);   //longer contours are cracks
    if (crackStats[i].axisMax > maxLenght)       // get longest crack
        biggest = i;
}
// DRAW AROUND BIGGER CRACKS
if (biggest > 0)  {
    cout << "Cracks Found! Biggest size: " << crackStats[biggest].axisMax <<
        "px (" << 100 * crackStats[biggest].axisMax / theBiscuit.axisMax << "%)" 
        << endl;
    RotatedRect rr = crackStats[biggest].rr;
    Point2f rect_points[4];
    rr.points(rect_points);
    //draw enclosing rectangle
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
        line(src, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j + 1) % 4], CL_RED, 1, 8);
    //draw major axis
    Point2f pt0 = (rect_points[0] + rect_points[3]) / 2.0;
    Point2f pt1 = (rect_points[1] + rect_points[2]) / 2.0;
    Point2f pt2 = (rect_points[0] + rect_points[1]) / 2.0;
    Point2f pt3 = (rect_points[2] + rect_points[3]) / 2.0;
    double axis1 = norm(pt0 - pt1);
    double axis2 = norm(pt2 - pt3);
    if (axis1>axis2)
        line(src, pt0, pt1, CL_BLACK, 2);
    else
        line(src, pt2, pt3, CL_BLACK, 2);
}
imshow("Src", src);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
void Morph(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, int operation,int kernel_type, int size)
{
cv::Point anchor = cv::Point(size, size);
cv::Mat element = getStructuringElement(kernel_type, cv::Size(2 * size +  1, 2 * size + 1), anchor);
morphologyEx(src, dst, operation, element, anchor);
}
```

Here is my image file of biscuit.....

[image]

Here the output of revised code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using opencv older version which do not support `drawMarker`. Opencv 3.1 suports it [click](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html)

I have made few change and now it is working. Please check...

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define CL_GREEN  Scalar(0  , 255, 0  )
#define CL_RED    Scalar(0  , 0  , 255)
#define CL_BLU    Scalar(255, 0  , 0  )
#define CL_BLACK  Scalar(0  , 0  , 0  )     

void Morph(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, int operation =    cv::MORPH_OPEN, 
int kernel_type = cv::MORPH_RECT, int size = 1);

struct contourStats
{
    double area, perimeter, axisMin, axisMax, axisAvg, eccentricity, axisRatio, circularity;
    Point2d center;
    RotatedRect rr;
    contourStats(){}

    contourStats(const vector<Point> &contour)
    {
        calculateStats(contour);
    }

    void calculateStats(const vector<Point> &contour)
    {
        Moments m = cv::moments(contour, true);
        area = m.m00;
        center = Point2f(-1, -1);
        if (area > 0){
            center.x = cvRound(m.m10 / m.m00);
            center.y = cvRound(m.m01 / m.m00);
        }
        eccentricity = DBL_MAX;
        if ((m.m20 + m.m02) > 0)
            eccentricity = (pow((m.m20 - m.m02), 2) - 4 * m.m11 * m.m11) / pow((m.m20 + m.m02), 2);
        // axis ratio:circles have ratio=1 lines have ratio->0
        rr = minAreaRect(contour);
        axisMin = min(rr.size.height, rr.size.width);
        axisMax = max(rr.size.height, rr.size.width);
        axisAvg = (axisMin+axisMax) / 2.0;
        axisRatio = axisMax > 0 ? axisMin / axisMax : 0;
        perimeter = arcLength(contour, false);
        circularity = perimeter > 0 ? 4 * CV_PI * area / pow(perimeter, 2) : 0;
    }

    void printStats(const string &title)
    {
        cout << endl << title << endl
            << "\tArea [px^2]: " << area << endl
            << "\tAxis[px]: " << axisMin << "/" << axisMax << endl
            << "\tAxis Ratio: " << axisRatio << endl
            << "\tCircularity: " << circularity << endl
            << "\tAbs(eccentricity): " << abs(eccentricity) << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src, gray, edges, cracks,tmp;
    Mat biscuitMask;
    //src = imread("../img/biscotto_rotated.jpg");
    src = imread("D:/bis.jpg");
    cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // GET ALL EDGES (CRACKS AND BISCUIT)
    Canny(gray, edges, 100, 200, 3);
    Morph(edges, edges, MORPH_CLOSE, MORPH_ELLIPSE, 5);
    // GET THE BISCUIT ONLY
    GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(7, 7), 0);
    threshold(gray, biscuitMask, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

    // VALIDATE THE BISCUIT
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    biscuitMask.copyTo(tmp);


    findContours(tmp, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    /*if ((contours.size() > 1) || (contours[0].size() < 6)) 
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: invalid mask for the biscuit!";
        return 1;
    }*/

    //taking largest contour
    int maxx = 0;
    int maxxIndx = -1;

    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<contours[i].size()<<endl;

        if(maxx < contours[i].size())
        {
            maxx = contours[i].size();
            maxxIndx = i;
        }

    }

    if(maxxIndx==-1)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: invalid mask for the biscuit!";
        return 1;
    }

    vector<Point> biscuitContour(contours[maxxIndx]);
    contourStats theBiscuit(biscuitContour);
    theBiscuit.printStats("BISCUIT STATS:");

    if (theBiscuit.circularity < 0.85) 
    {
        cout << "WARNING: invalid biscuit circularity!";
    }

    //drawMarker(src, theBiscuit.center, CL_BLU, MARKER_CROSS, theBiscuit.axisAvg / 8);
    circle(src, theBiscuit.center, theBiscuit.axisAvg / 2, CL_BLU, 2);
    //polylines(src, biscuitContour, true, CL_GREEN); 

    // GET ONLY THE CRACKS INSIDE THE BISCUIT
    Morph(biscuitMask, biscuitMask, MORPH_ERODE,MORPH_ELLIPSE, 5);
    cracks = (edges & biscuitMask);
    imshow("cracks", cracks);

    findContours(cracks, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    double minLenght = theBiscuit.axisAvg / 2;
    double maxLenght = 0;
    int biggest = -1;
    vector<contourStats> crackStats(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(src, contours, i, CL_GREEN, 1); //all contours in GREEN
        crackStats[i].calculateStats(contours[i]);   //analize potential cracks
        if (crackStats[i].axisMax < minLenght)       //ignore short contours
            continue;
        drawContours(src, contours, i, CL_RED, 1);   //longer contours are cracks
        if (crackStats[i].axisMax > maxLenght)       // get longest crack
            biggest = i;
    }
    // DRAW AROUND BIGGER CRACKS
    if (biggest > 0)  
    {
        cout << "Cracks Found! Biggest size: " << crackStats[biggest].axisMax <<
            "px (" << 100 * crackStats[biggest].axisMax / theBiscuit.axisMax << "%)" 
            << endl;
        RotatedRect rr = crackStats[biggest].rr;
        Point2f rect_points[4];
        rr.points(rect_points);
        //draw enclosing rectangle
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
            line(src, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j + 1) % 4], CL_RED, 1, 8);

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
        {
            rect_points[j].x = rect_points[j].x / 2.0;
            rect_points[j].y = rect_points[j].x / 2.0;
        }
        //draw major axis
        Point2f pt0 = (rect_points[0] + rect_points[3]);
        Point2f pt1 = (rect_points[1] + rect_points[2]);
        Point2f pt2 = (rect_points[0] + rect_points[1]);
        Point2f pt3 = (rect_points[2] + rect_points[3]);

        double axis1 = norm(pt0 - pt1);
        double axis2 = norm(pt2 - pt3);
        if (axis1>axis2)
            line(src, pt0, pt1, CL_BLACK, 2);
        else
            line(src, pt2, pt3, CL_BLACK, 2);
    }

    imshow("Src", src);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}


void Morph(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, int operation,int kernel_type, int size)
{
cv::Point anchor = cv::Point(size, size);
cv::Mat element = getStructuringElement(kernel_type, cv::Size(2 * size +  1, 2 * size + 1), anchor);
morphologyEx(src, dst, operation, element, anchor);
}
```

Comment: can you upload the expected output image?